# template repeat dynamic object in polymer table

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I am trying to create custom table-element,
how can i repeat over dynamic object, by knowing its field names?

```dart
<tr template repeat="{{row in rows}}">
   <td template repeat="{{field in fields}}">
      {{row.field}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

table_elemnet.html

```dart
<polymer-element name = "table-element" attributes ="structure data">
     <template>
         <table class="bordered" id="table_element">
             <tr>
                 <th template repeat="{{col in cols}}">
                     {{col}}
                 </th>
             </tr>
             <tr template repeat="{{row in rows}}">
                 <td template repeat="{{field in fields}}">
                     {{row.field}}
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </template>
<script type="application/dart" src="table_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

table_element.dart

```dart
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";


/**
 * Custom table element
 *
 */

@CustomTag("table-element")
class Table extends PolymerElement {

 @published List<Map<String,String>>  structure; // table struture column name and value factory
 @published List<dynamic> data; // table data

 @observable List<dynamic> rows = toObservable([]);
 @observable List<String> cols = [];
 @observable List<String> fields = [];

 static const  COLUMN_NAME = "columnName";
 static  const FIELD_NAME = "fieldName";

  Table.created():super.created();

  void enteredView() {
     super.enteredView();
     structure.forEach((map)  { cols.add(map[COLUMN_NAME]); fields.add(map[FIELD_NAME]);}); // populate columns and fields from table
     rows.addAll(data);
  }
}
```

Attribute values from test element :

```dart
List<People> data = [new People("name1","name2"),new People("name2","name4")];
List<Map<String,String>> structure = [{ "columnName" : "First Name", "fieldName" : "fname"},
                                                         {"columnName" : "Last Name", "fieldName" : "lname"}];
```

In browser i am able to see column names but not data ..

**Edit :**

I changed rows type to `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` and populated rows using dart mirrors ,now row[field] is working fine ,as i am just reading map .

```dart
 if(data != null) {
      data.forEach((element) { // kind of hackish dynamic object iteration
        Map row ={};
       fields.forEach((field) {
         row[field] = reflect(element).getField(new Symbol(field)).reflectee;} );
        rows.add(row);
      });
    }
```

is there any way i can create custom expression which will take care of reflection logic and use it in polymer elements .. ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make `cols` and `fields` observable with `toObservable([])` like you have done with `rows` so the view get's notified about updates.
This might not be necessary if the values are static, but then you have to ensure the values are assigned **before** the bindings are evaluated (<del>`enteredView()`</del>`attached()` after the <del>`super.enteredView()`</del> `super.attached()` call is definitely to late (in your case 'data' will not be set yet, so you should use `toObservable()`.
I think the callback method `polymerCreated` (before the `super.polymerCreated()` call should work.

I guess instead of `{{row.field}}` you want `{{row[field]}}`

If it still doesn't work please add a comment the I'll look for other causes.

Comment: data is populating fine ,if i use <tr template repeat="{{row in rows}}">
   <td>
      {{row.fname}}
   </td>
</tr> , {{row[field]}} also didn't worked for me :(

Comment: I saw that you wrote `able to see column names` and I wonder why this works. You should also verify if this works in JavaScript this way after you solved the main problem (data not show).

Comment: for row[field] i am getting following error Uncaught Error: Class 'People' has no instance method '[]'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of 'People'
Arguments: ["fname"] ,any thing special i have to add to my Person class to access fields in this way ?

Comment: It's a bit cumbersome to analyze this code/data what it actually does. I think you should add an [] operator to the People class to be able to access the fields this way. I don't think this is going to work like you tried in your question that Polymer creates method/field names from values at runtime and access them.

Comment: i changed rows type to List<Map<String,dynamic>> ,and used dart mirrors to populate data to rows from objects ,now row[field] works fine , is there any way i can put all this reflection code in the form of expression and use it in custom element declaration ?

Comment: I see. I don't think there is a way to do this declaratively or in any other way without reflection. The one alternative is to implement the `[]` operator I already mentioned but then the operator implementation needs to map the field names to a concrete fields.

Comment: i can do that ,but i am more interested in solving that in custom table element itself ,forcing the users of table-elements is not a good idea ...